# Can I convert sparse array into string?

Tags: java, android, qr-code, barcode

I'm working on QR code scanning app. I'm using Barcode Detector to read QR code and the result is storing in SparseArray. So my question is can I convert SparseArray into String? So that I can break the string using Split function and later compare it with another String.

```
@Override
        public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
            final SparseArray<Barcode> qrcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();


            if (qrcodes.size() != 0) {
                txtResult.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        vibrator.vibrate(100);

                        txtResult.setText(qrcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);


                    }
                });
            }

        }
```

Comment: `sparseArray.toString()`. Or did you mean something else? Also why build a string from a collection only to split it back into a collection? That seems useless.

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? Your `SparseArray` doesn't contain strings, it contains `Barcode`s. Please explain what you are trying to "compare"?

Comment: So the QR contain a url with a number separated by ';'. I'm trying to split it and compare the url in QR code and the one I have to.

Answer (score 1):

Siimply You can use `toString()` method like: `SparseArray<Int>().toString()`.
If you are dealing with Built-in class( library classes ), Extend that class to customize any behavior you want, For Example:

```
class b<T> : SparseArray<T>(){

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return //customised String;
 }
}
```

After this you can call `SparseArray<Int>().toString()` to get your customize String representation.